# how to add external style sheet and js files to jsfiddle

Tags: javascript

i am trying to create a fiddle which includes an external css style sheet and an external javascript file which .it had an option in the left panel called external resources.how this option can be used to add those external files?do i need to upload the external files to somewhere.if i need to would you please give me the link where i can upload this.

```
HTML:
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="games.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv">
<canvas id="mycanvas1"></canvas>
<canvas id="mycanvas2"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{margin:0px;padding:0px;}
#mydiv{
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:black;
}
#mycanvas1{
width:500px;
height:500px;
background-color:white;
border:1px solid white;

}
```

Comment: Just upload them anywhere where they can be publicly accessed from via HTTP …

Comment: You just paste the URL in the input field and click the add button. See http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#fiddle-settings-sidebar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to load an external resource in JsFiddle you need to place it somewhere that JsFiddle can find it.

For example, if you have a website `http://www.example.com` you could place your external file in the web root so that it has a URL of `http://www.example.com/resource.css`. That's the value you put in the external resources field on JSFiddle.

You'll need to upload your files to somewhere - JSFiddle doesn't have access to your hard disk. Where you put it is something you'll have to decide for yoursefl.

Comment: is there any websites which allows me to edit texts.i am not going to post codes on my facebook account :\

Comment: If you're asking where you can get a free hosting account then your question is off-topic for [so]

Answer (score 1):

***If you refer something like jquery plugins or jquery ui or simply jquery plugin and other optional css which are taken from other websites where you would like to use it for your reference in your page you need to add those links which you are seeing it on you left side of jsfilddle.***

For ex: `<script src="http://somewebsite.com/yourfile.js"></script>`

you need to add `"yourfile.js"` to your hosting server and the refer it as

`http://somewebsite.com/yourfile.js` in the exernal js file in fiddle

Comment: Eh? Could you add some punctuation please?

Comment: actually i want to add css and pure js file.it simply draw an image on the canvas