# Getting black screen in three.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

I have followed the three.js example and loaded object. All is working fine. But I am not getting why background color is not showing. Its getting black color.

I tried to figure it out from css but not able to find it out the cause of getting black color. There are **no errors** in the code. So difficult to figure out the problem.

Comment: Can you try to get a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), so we can better help you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23976979/how-to-add-external-style-sheet-and-js-files-to-jsfiddle

Comment: might be helpful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177056/changing-three-js-background-to-transparent-or-other-color

Comment: @Danbopes: not able to put code on jsfiddle. its contains many external links.

Comment: ok. trying that. thanks.

Comment: @Kheema Pandey: hey thanks for that link. its showing background color now.

Comment: Glad your problem solved :)